# Does Apache Kylin can still work with Mondrian 4.4 and Saiku CE?

Tags: hive, hbase, mondrian, saiku, kylin

I am using :

```
Apache Hadoop 2.7.3
Apache HBase 1.2.4
Apache Hive 2.1.1
Apache Kylin 2.6.1
Saiku
Mondrian 4.4 Dialect Kylin
```

I've managed to create a schema and i saw it on my cube list from saiku but i couldnt get any data from it!

checked my saiku log and i found this!

```
2019-04-20 22:09:18,050 INFO  [org.saiku.datasources.connection.SaikuOlapConnection] Catalogs:1
2019-04-20 22:09:21,807 DEBUG [org.saiku.web.rest.resources.Query2Resource] TRACK       /query/50A71ADC-DD5D-C4A4-AEFC-384907016FF3 POST     tq:false file:null

2019-04-20 22:09:52,730 DEBUG [org.saiku.service.datasource.RepositoryDatasourceManager] file did not exist

2019-04-20 22:14:56,148 DEBUG [org.saiku.web.rest.resources.Query2Resource] TRACK       /query/AB4B2C0B-51D8-72F6-901C-6DA5085BD402 POST     tq:false file:null

2019-04-20 22:14:56,964 ERROR [org.saiku.web.rest.InfoResource] /etc/theme/cssoverride.less
2019-04-20 22:14:59,468 DEBUG [org.saiku.web.rest.resources.Query2Resource] TRACK       /query/E78B5A72-3348-A912-AF77-BB9ACD1E3E48 POST     tq:false file:null

2019-04-20 22:23:52,244 ERROR [org.saiku.web.rest.InfoResource] /etc/theme/cssoverride.less
2019-04-20 22:23:58,715 DEBUG [org.saiku.web.rest.resources.Query2Resource] TRACK       /query/E133F2AC-756D-17D4-AC8C-507BA164E39B POST     tq:false file:null
```

I found in this article that only kylin 1.5 works well with saiku
https://www.jianshu.com/p/e2fee07fd58e

is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

was there any error log in your kylin.log after you queried on saiku.

Comment: I think there are some exceptions, but i am not sure it is from saiku or from somewhere else ! thank you for your response, it made me remember to read the log